# R TimeSeries Plotting for Weekly Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

I have weekly data starting from week 2 in the year 2015 till week 9 in 2016, after fitting and plotting my forecast, The x-axis doesn't make sense. How can I share x-axis values in terms of months/week#. Thank you

[image: Current Forecast Plot]

```
TS1<-ts(DUMMYDATA,frequency =52,start = c(2015,02),end = c(2016,09))
```

I tried creating my own x-axis but I am not able to reflect it correctly in terms of Time components

Answer (score 1):

First I generated some random reproducible data. You could directly generate dates in your `ts` with `as.Date`. After that you need to convert the time series to a date format. To show the axis with month/weeks dates, you can use `scale_x_date` with `date_labels` form week and month. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Generate random reproducible data
set.seed(1)
DUMMYDATA <- cumsum(rnorm(10000))
TS1<-ts(DUMMYDATA, frequency = 52, start = as.Date('2015-02-01'), end = as.Date('2016-09-01'))

# Convert to dataframe
data = data.frame(y=as.matrix(TS1), date=time(TS1))

# convert date to date format
data$date <- as.Date(as.numeric(time(data$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")

ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%W", 
               date_breaks = '1 week') +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you don't want to show each week, you can change `date_breaks` to months like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x = date, y = y)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%W", 
               date_breaks = '1 month') +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a `tsibble` object rather than a `ts` object. Here is an example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)
library(lubridate)
library(feasts)

set.seed(1)
df <- tsibble(
  Week = yearweek(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length=300, by="7 days")),
  TS1 = cumsum(rnorm(300))
)
#> Using `Week` as index variable.
df |> autoplot(TS1) +
  scale_x_yearweek(date_breaks = '1 year')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

It appears that you are using the `forecast` package to create forecasts from `ts` objects. The equivalent functionality is provided in the `fable` package to create forecasts from `tsibble` objects. See [my book](https://OTexts.com/fpp3) for lots of examples, including using weekly data.